# Application opens gallery instead of camera - XCode, SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, xcode, swiftui

I have an application which has the goal of opening the camera to take a picture. The picture will then be analyzed, but that comes later. My issue lies in the fact that when the button that *should* open the camera, instead of the camera opening, the gallery opens where I can select an image that is already on the device.

**this is my AppDelegate.swift file**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  application2
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

**this is my SceneDelegate.swift file**

```
//
//  SceneDelegate.swift
//  application2
//

import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

**this is my ContentView.swift file**

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  application2
//


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State private var image: Image? = nil

    // Function that converts an UIImage to Image
    func returnImage() -> Image
    {
        guard let img = image else {
            fatalError("Unable to load image")
        }
        return img
//        return Image(uiImage: img)
    }


    // Main Body
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{

            VStack {

                image?.resizable().scaledToFit()

                Button("Open Camera"){
                    self.showImagePicker = true
                }.padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color.purple)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker){
                PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image)
            }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Camera"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**this is my imagePicker.swift file**

```
//
//  ImagePicker.swift
//  application2
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate,
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@Binding var isShown: Bool
@Binding var image: Image?

init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
    _isShown = isShown
    _image = image
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
    image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    isShown = false

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    isShown = false
}

}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Binding var isShown: Bool
@Binding var image: Image?

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

}

func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerCoordinator {
    return ImagePickerCoordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    return picker
}

}

struct CameraPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Binding var isShown: Bool
@Binding var image: Image?

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraPicker>) {

}

func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerCoordinator {
    return ImagePickerCoordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraPicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = .camera
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        } else {
            picker.sourceType = .camera
        }
        return picker
    }
    return picker
}

}

struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Binding var isShown: Bool
@Binding var image: Image?

func makeCoordinator() -> CameraView.Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraView>) -> UIViewController {
    let cameraViewController = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
    cameraViewController.sourceType = .camera
    cameraViewController.allowsEditing = false
    return cameraViewController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraView>) {

}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var parent: CameraView

    init(_ cameraView: CameraView) {
        self.parent = cameraView
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        parent.image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        parent.isShown = false
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        parent.isShown = false
    }
}
}
```

**this is my PhotoCaptureView.swift file**

```
//
//  PhotoCaptureView.swift
//  application2
//


import SwiftUI

struct PhotoCaptureView: View {

    @Binding var showImagePicker: Bool
    @Binding var image: Image?

    var body: some View {
        ImagePicker(isShown: $showImagePicker, image: $image)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct PhotoCaptureView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: .constant(false), image: .constant(Image("")))
    }
}
#endif
```

Any help is appreciated. If you think that anything that I am doing is unnecessary or could be done better feel free to let me know. I am a new app developer and am not very experienced. Most of what I have is stuff I found from other posts here and on google.

Comment: You didn’t include the code for ImagePicker, but rather pasted your ContentView code a second time. ImagePicker is probably where the problem is — it’s a wrapper for UIImagePickerController I assume?

Comment: @Adam my mistake. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I see three attempts to wrap UIImagePickerController in your code:

1. ImagePicker, which will show the photo library because no sourceType is set.
2. CameraPicker, which seems to have a copy-paste error that duplicates its makeUIViewController method… one of the methods appears to set sourceType to camera if possible.
3. CameraView, which sets its sourceType to camera.

I only see you *using* ImagePicker, which is the library one. Fix CameraPicker and use that instead.

Comment: Is there any way that you could give me an example as to how to fix these mistakes. I have been looking at this for a while and cant figure it out. I apologize I'm new to app development.